# Cannot pass nested array of hashes to ansible.host_vars in Vagrant's ansible_local provisioner

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm trying to add a custom HBA entry to allow the host machine to connect to a PostgreSQL instance running on the Vagrant box:

```
config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
  ansible.playbook = "provisioning/playbook.yml"
  ansible.galaxy_role_file = "provisioning/requirements.yml"
  ansible.host_vars = {
    "default" => {
      "postgresql_listen_addresses" => "*",
      "postgresql_pg_hba_custom" => [{
        "type" => "host",
        "database" => "vagrant",
        "user" => "vagrant",
        "address" => "samenet",
        "method" => "password"
      }],
      "database_name" => "vagrant",
      "database_username" => "vagrant",
      "database_password" => "password",
      "node_environment" => "development"
    }
  }
end
```

I'm getting the error:

> AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'type'

How can I pass a nested (complex) configuration value for a host variable *right inside my Vagrantfile*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check how the host variables are encoded in a single line for a host entry in the automatically generated inventory file, /tmp/vagrant-ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_local_inventory:

```
# Generated by Vagrant

default ... postgresql_pg_hba_custom=[{"type"=>"host", "database"=>"vagrant", "user"=>"vagrant", "address"=>"samenet", "method"=>"password"}] database_name=vagrant database_username=vagrant database_password=password node_environment=development
```

The value passed to postgresql_pg_hba_custom is not in a valid format.

The [Ansible documentation on variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) states:

> As of Ansible 1.2, you can also pass in extra vars as quoted JSON, like so:
>
> `--extra-vars '{"pacman":"mrs","ghosts":["inky","pinky","clyde","sue"]}'`

So, you should pass complex values as JSON wrapped inside single-quotes. Instead of manually crafting the value, you can make use of Ruby's [JSON module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) and string interpolation:

```
config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
  require 'json'

  postgresql_pg_hba_custom = [{
    "type" => "host",
    "database" => "vagrant",
    "user" => "vagrant",
    "address" => "samenet",
    "method" => "password"
  }]

  ansible.playbook = "provisioning/playbook.yml"
  ansible.galaxy_role_file = "provisioning/requirements.yml"
  ansible.host_vars = {
    "default" => {
      "postgresql_listen_addresses" => "*",
      "postgresql_pg_hba_custom" => "'#{postgresql_pg_hba_custom.to_json}'",
      "database_name" => "vagrant",
      "database_username" => "vagrant",
      "database_password" => "password",
      "node_environment" => "development"
    }
  }
end
```

The generated inventory file will now be:

```
# Generated by Vagrant

default ... postgresql_pg_hba_custom='[{"type":"host","database":"vagrant","user":"vagrant","address":"samenet","method":"password"}]' database_name=vagrant database_username=vagrant database_password=password node_environment=development
```